# PageController in OS x application

Tags: macos, cocoa, uipagecontrol

I need to implement a UIPageController like thing in my OS x application. But I couldn't find any default controls in mac library. Anyone knows how to implement it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simple way is to use a tab view.